# PayPal Rest API: How to disable registration/pay with creditcard dialog at express checkout

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am wondering whether there is an option at PayPals Rest API to disable the registration dialog in the user approval dialog (@see screenshot).

[image]

I am using the php-sdk (https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) and I have set the payment method exclusively to 'paypal' in the order creation process:

```
$payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");
...
$payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
$payment->setPayer($payer);
...
$payment->create($this->_getApiContext());
```

I also have checked the experience API (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-a-web-experience-profile), but there seems to be no option either.

Am I missing something or is there just no possibility to hide this dialog?

**Edit:** My requirement is to have no second option, just the plain PayPal login.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue properly with the REST api? The accepted answer suggests mixed results.

Comment: As far as I can remember there was no way to disable the second option.

Comment: Bugger. Its amazing how little documentation and information there is out there for the PHP PayPal SDK! It's almost like they just don't care ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where available, Guest Checkout would take the place of the account creation requirement. Guest Checkout is a PayPal Account Optional payment method. 
You will need to ensure that you have a [Business Verified PayPal Account](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/article/?articleID=FAQ1014&m=SRE&url=https%253A%252F%252Fokminternal.paypal.com%252Finfocenter%252Findex%253Fpage%253Dcontent%2526id%253DFAQ1014%2526actp%253Dsearch%2526viewlocale%253Den_US&answerId=16777218&searchId=1438025582207&rankId=3) and ensure you have Guest Checkout Enabled in your PayPal account 
From the PayPal Developer Site:
[Rest API Accept a PayPal Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/)

> Important: To receive Guest Checkout payments, which allow credit cards, ensure that PayPal Account Optional is enabled on your account settings. For example, here is the path for US accounts:
>       Profile > My selling tools > Website preferences > PayPal Account Optional

The PayPal Hosted Page depending on the country will either have the Guest Checkout Option (Account Optional/Pay with Credit Card) or Create a PayPal Account.

Comment: Thanks, but my requirement is paypal login only, without guest checkout or account creation. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: For PayPal Standard and Express Checkout the PayPal hosted page will give the option of Account Creation or paying with a credit or debit card. To make it a little cleaner, you can setup in Context Checkout. [In Context information](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/) which displays the checkout in an iFrame.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Does the 'in context'-workflow work with the rest API or is it only available for the classical API?

Comment: In context is currently available for Express Checkout Classic API, Express Checkout Payflow Edition API, and Adaptive Payments. It looks like this feature is not available at this time for Rest API.