# How do I remove a "Ship to" section from Checkout Popup?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, express-checkout

Is there any option, when creating a payment with Paypal API, that allows to remove a "Ship to" section from Checkout popup? I mean just not to displayit in popup.

I do not use a `shipping_address` [option](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#definition-shipping_address) anywhere in `payment_json` object when creating a configuration for a payment. But the section still persists.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Payment Experience API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/?mark=Presentation).

Create new web_profile, and set presentation with

```
"no_shipping": 1,
"address_override": 0
```

Comment: Nice to hear it is configurable. Finally I have returned to the task again and am going to try it out. I will write my experience.

Comment: Yep, that's true. Answer is accepted. Don't you know by chance how to offer user to select a credit card for payment? Currently PP behavior is that it offers user only user's PP balance to make a payment with. But how may I give user an option to select a payment option, either PP account or a credit card

Comment: Hope, this will help - [PayPal Rest API: How to disable registration/pay with creditcard dialog at express checkout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655313/paypal-rest-api-how-to-disable-registration-pay-with-creditcard-dialog-at-expre)

Answer (score 5):

I'm adding this answer since I came here while searching for disabling the shipping to information by using **PayPal Smart Payment Button**. This answer may help them.

You have to add the below line to remove Ship to address.

**application_context: { shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING' }**

Eg:

```
paypal.Buttons({
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [{ amount: { value: 1.00 } }],
      application_context: { shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING' }
    });
  }
}).render("#paypal-button-container");
```